# Nesting scrollable's in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Compose do not allow nesting of scrollable's in the same direction.
But I have use case where layout consist of multiple sections. Each section can be a list, a grid, regular text etc... The entire layout is scrollable.

Recyclerview supports having multiple view types ( e.g. where a view can be another recyclerview which is a grid based)

But in compose, if you use a `lazycolumn` so that the entire layout is scrollable, you no longer can use `LazyHorizontalGrid` and `LazyVerticalGrid` inside it. You have to build your grid using a `column`

Any idea on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this as modifier inside your surface or box:

```
modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(rememberViewInteropNestedScrollConnection())
```

then you can easily use lazyHorizontalGrid like this:

```
 LazyColumn {
            //other contents
            item {
                LazyHorizontalGrid(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(176.dp), // itemHeight * rowCount + verticalSpacing * (rowCount - 1)
                    rows = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                ) {
                    items(arrayList.size) {
                        Text(arrayList[it], modifier = Modifier.height(48.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: what's up with the rememberViewInteropNestedScrollConnection()? didn't follow

Answer (score 0):

its quite easy, I figured it out.. say we have a data structure
(in kotlin)

Making a nested vertical List in Jetpack Compose.

```
val allTransactions = List<Transaction>

val monthlyTransaction = Transaction(monthName: String, monthlyTransactions: List< MonthlyTransactions>)

val monthlyTransaction = MonthlyTransaction(amount: String, date: String)
```

```
@Composable
fun mainFunction (){
    // first have a LazyColumn

    LazyColumn {
        if (allTransactions.isNotEmpty()) {
            items(allTransactions.size) { index ->
                // pass each model
                TransactionComposable(model = allTransactions[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TransactionComposable(transaction: SurfaceControl.Transaction) {

    // make the title outside the column so it will be on top of the list
    Text(text = transaction.monthName)

    Column {
        // make a for each loop inside the column
        transaction.monthlyTransactions.forEach { monthlyTransaction ->
                // for each of your iteration, call your inner list item inside a a row
                Row {
                    TransactionDetailComponent (monthlyTransaction)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```